Regarding Order of a function.
While going through VI Arnold's MMCM, I came across the following definition on Pg 56. I will present the relevant part here

... and R(h,$\gamma$)=$O$($h^2$), in the sense that for |h|<$\epsilon$ and |dh/dt|<$\epsilon$, we have |R|<$C\epsilon^{2}$...

Here $\gamma$ is a curve defined by parameters $t$ (not necessarily time) and $x$ (not necessarily position) and $h(t)$ is another function added to the curve $\gamma$ to generate a variation or departure.
My MAIN question is regarding how Order of a function is defined:
Why is there an additional condition on the derivative also being bounded along the function, and that too by same $\epsilon$ ? Would it not suffice to just having the function being bounded??

Suffice for what? What is the context of that definition?

The definition is given in context of a differential of a functional. Which has a linear part and a part which is O(h^2). The author had defined Order in the above manner.

Suffice as in, is not sufficient for the function to be bounded, why keep the derivative also bounded. If not, why?
